# Does konsole support a visible bell?

Tags: notifications, konsole

I would like to set up my terminal to use a visible bell notification. Konsole is my preferred terminal emulator, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Everything I can find on the web points me towards `set bell-style visible` in `.bashrc`, or towards Settings->Configure Notifications. The bash setting seems to have no effect, and under configure notifications, none of the options corresponds to a visible bell.
[image: konsole notification settings]

P.S. for extra credit, if anyone knows why konsole started ignoring the characters "s" and "v" from either keyboard or clipboard when I tried the following in bashrc, I can add that as a separate question: `bind bell-style visible`

Comment: By "visible bell notification" do you mean a popup notification? I have that in place for "Bell in non-visible session". It should work the same for "Bell in visible session".

Comment: I'd prefer something a little less intrusive, like a brief colour inversion. I really don't want to have to take any action to stop the bell.

Comment: Hmm. You might get some clues at http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Visual-Bell.html#s6 . I'm not aware of anything specific to Konsole.

Comment: @JoeP That's not relevant. Konsole ignores the terminal's visual bell setting that can be set by applications, it always performs the action(s) configured in its preferences, and these don't include a traditional visual bell.

Comment: For the extra credit: it's `bind 'set bell-style visible'`. Bash does strange things when a readline command is malformed instead of showing a proper error message.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. It sounds like the answer to my question is "no". If you want to convert your comment an answer, I'll accept & upvote.

Comment: I don't think the answer is no. It's probably doable with the right command, at least in the case where the konsole window is active.

Comment: Good idea! I've now written up a custom command that flashes the window using xcalib. I'll give you a chance to write up an answer if you want, otherwise I'll add my own in a day or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gilles' hints, I put together something that flashes the command window when there is a bell in a visible session. To do this I wrote a quick bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#flash console as a visible bell
#requires installation of xcalib

xcalib -i -a
sleep 0.01
xcalib -i -a
```

and entered the full path to this script under "Run command" for "Bell in Visible Session" in the konsole "Configure Notifications" dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it was the case back when this question was asked, but the main bell settings are separate from those notifications settings.

Open *Settings > Configure Konsole > Profiles*, select a profile (you may need to create a new one if you have only the read-only default), then click *Edit*. On the *General* tab of the subsequent dialogue, there is a setting at the bottom called *Terminal bell mode*, and there is a *Visual Bell* option which inverts the colours.